# Disable or override Spring association resources

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Is there a way to disable or override the association resources that Spring Data REST provides by default?

For example, if you have the Library object which can be linked to many Address objects, the ability to link an address to the library is readily supported by doing the following request:

```
curl -i -X PUT -d "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
  -H "Content-Type:text/uri-list" http://localhost:8080/libraries/1/libraryAddress
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships

Let's say, I would like to add a limit on the no. of addresses that can be added to the library. I would either :

1. create a custom endpoint and disable this
2. OR (if possible) just override the part when this kind request is being handled.

Comment: *Is there a way to disable or override*. You will need to expand your question to detail more clearly what it is you want to do. Possbiby, give the current JSON representation and how you would like it to look.

Comment: @AlanHay I simply want to disable that endpoint since I want to add validation on how my entities are linked.

Comment: I'd probably just add some validation. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators

Comment: @AlanHay doesn't seem to work for objects with MongoDB DBRefs. When that PUT request above is being done, the validation isnt being invoked. When doing normal PUT to the object (from my example, the library obj) the validation is being invoked.

Comment: I'm thinking of adding that validation in the beforeSave AbstractMongoEventListener. But, I'm not certain if it's the best solution.

Comment: But thanks for the suggestion on Spring Rest validators, @AlanHay. I wasn't aware of that before, so I learned something new! Thank you!